# Google Chrome says "your connection to this site is not secure" on ubuntu, is it safe to use?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, ssl, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop, and installed Google Chrome version: `google-chrome-stable (55.0.2883.87-1)`

When I try to open gmail.com or any https site (for that matter even www.google.com), I get an an error as shown in screen shot with description.

So is it not safe to use chrome?

Any solution for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume the certificate could not be verified. A pretty common error for this would be an incorrect System time. Furthermore, check if all necessary certificates are installed (I do not use ubuntu, but I think they are installed by default).

Check Ubuntus Certificate help page for further information: [Certificates and Security at help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html)